# defect in afterAction in Yii

Tags: php, redirect, yii

when i use redirect in an action , afterAction method (in controller.php) does not work !!
how can i fix this problem ?

note:i can not use beforeAction because i am generating a variable in my action and i use this in afterAction 
thanks in advance ...

```
    public function actionHsh()
    {
        $this->hesam= 502;
        $this->redirect(array('charge/printMyCharge'));
    }
```

And in CController

```
    protected function afterAction($action)
    { 
       $number = $this->hesam= 502;

    }
```

Comment: it will not work because first the redirect is called an then after action... the problem is, upon calling redirect, you are already in a different action, so the afterAction is not called anymore... you will have to force call afterAction before you call the redirect ;)

Comment: I think you have to return true or false like beforesave

Comment: Is there any other code in the `afterAction`? You are not doing anything with `$number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use afteraction before redirect
enjoy it!

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with "*why is it not working?*". Because [`CController::redirect()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/web/CController.php#L1023) is defined like this:

```
public function redirect($url,$terminate=true,$statusCode=302)
{
    if(is_array($url))
    {
        $route=isset($url[0]) ? $url[0] : '';
        $url=$this->createUrl($route,array_splice($url,1));
    }
    Yii::app()->getRequest()->redirect($url,$terminate,$statusCode);
}
```

and [`CHttpRequest::redirect()`](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.15/framework/web/CHttpRequest.php#L799) is defined like this:

```
public function redirect($url,$terminate=true,$statusCode=302)
{
    if(strpos($url,'/')===0 && strpos($url,'//')!==0)
        $url=$this->getHostInfo().$url;
    header('Location: '.$url, true, $statusCode);
    if($terminate)
        Yii::app()->end(); // Notice this? We only stop when $terminate is true
}
```

---

Essentially there's two things you can do.

**1)** Use `redirect($url, false)` to avoid the termination

**2)** extend the `redirect` method in your controller:

```
class Foo extends CController 
{
    public function redirect($url,$terminate=true,$statusCode=302)
    {
        if (method_exists($this, 'afterAction')) {
            $this->afterAction(null);
        }

        parent::redirect($url,$terminate,$statusCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: His original code had `redirect($url, false)` but an edit removed it: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26908529/revisions